# Redirect back to admin area after customer session has closed.

Tags: admin, redirect, frontend

I have developed a custom module with the help from @Marius, that allows a customer support team member to select a customer from the customer list in the admin section and logs them in as the customer and then redirects to shop.

I now need to the opposite, from a custom page in the client side I need to:

1. Clear the customer session
2. Redirect back to the customer list in the admin section.

This is the code I have in a new controller:

```
 // get customer list in admin section URL
 $customerUrl = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/customer/index');
 // Logout customer session 
 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout()->renewSession();
 // Redirect to customers page in admin section
 Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($customerUrl);
```

This code kind works but I get redirect to the admin dashboard.

Please can you point me in the direction

Many thanks

Si

Answer (score 1):

I think the following snippet should do what you need here.

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/customer/index"));
```